# Using SYSCTRL on an arduino DUE

Tags: arduino, arduino-due

I'm currently working on a project using a timer interruption i found on the web few years ago. My code is working fine on an arduino m0 or M0 pro, bu i tried to compile it on an Arduino DUE, and this error appeared :

```
'SYSCTRL' was not declare in this scope
```

(I'm using SYSCTRL on this line of the timer :

```
SYSCTRL->XOSC32K.bit.RUNSTDBY = 1;
```

I'm pretty sure this is a hardware difference between the M0/M0pro and the Arduino DUE which is causing this issue, but i have no idea how to resolve it....

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much you would have to change in your code, it might be worth switching over to the [DueTimer](https://github.com/ivanseidel/DueTimer)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will definitely try this and keep you in touch !